# Solve a bunch of Visual Studio git conflicts

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have merged two git branches in VS.

I got about fivethousand conflicts, about a hundred of which were actual code. These hundred I happily resolved.

Now there are still about fivethousand conflicts left, all of them being that binary files by the same name were added to branch 2 and changed in branch 1. Not sure, but I think the file content should even be the same.

How can I resolve these conflicts, automatically, without doing it one file at a time, and without losing my already-merged code files?

I tried to delete all these binary files from the checkout location, but not only didn't this resolve the problem, it even stopped VS from accepting manual resolve, so I had to restore them all from recycle bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently not a way to bulk resolve Git conflicts in Visual Studio. However, you can resolve conflicts through the command line, and Visual Studio will no longer report these as conflicted files.

After you resolve and stage the resolution of a conflict through the command line, Visual Studio will no longer report that as a conflicted file.

Comment: You should probably add how you would do so using the command line, at a minimum provide a link.